# Como passar múltiplos arquivos com click python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, script, linha-de-comando

Tenho um diretório com vários arquivos:

```
arquivo.txt
arquivo1.txt
arquivo2.txt...
```

E tenho esse código:

```
import click
@click.command()
@click.argument("file", type=click.File('r'))

def cat(file):
    click.echo(f.read())

cat()
```

Porém esse código só pega um arquivo. Ele não faz um for no diretório. Gostaria de abrir e ler cada um dos arquivos do diretório...

Tentei alguns outros códigos mas não estão funcionando também

```
@click.command()
@click.argument("file", type=click.File())
lista = open(file, 'r')
lista_lines = lista.readlines()
for lista_line in lista_lines:
     cat(lista_line)

 def cat(lista_line):
        click.echo(f.read())
```

Como posso rodar o script uma vez de modo que ele consiga abrir todos arquivos do diretório?

Answer (score 1):

> Eu fiz de cabeça pois não vou instalar o módulo [click](https://palletsprojects.com/p/click/) em meu sistema.
> Teste os exemplos....

A biblioteca padrão do Python inclui o módulo *[os](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/os.html) — Diversas interfaces de sistema operacional*, que inclui em seu acervo a função [listdir()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) que segundo a documentação:

> **`os.listdir(path='.')`**
> Retorna uma lista contendo os nomes das entradas no diretório fornecido por path. A lista está em ordem arbitrária e não inclui as
> entradas especiais '.' e '..' mesmo se estiverem presentes no
> diretório. Se um arquivo for removido ou adicionado ao diretório
> durante a chamada desta função, não é especificado se um nome para
> esse arquivo deve ser incluído.
>
> *path* pode ser um objeto caminho ou similar. Se path for do tipo bytes (direta ou indiretamente por meio da interface PathLike), os
> nomes de arquivo retornados também serão do tipo bytes; em todas as
> outras circunstâncias, eles serão do tipo str.
>
> Esta função também pode ter suporte a especificar um descritor de arquivo; o descritor de arquivo deve fazer referência a um diretório.

```
import os

@click.command()
@click.option("--path", default=".", help="Path para ser listado.")
def ls1(path):
  for f in os.listdir("path"):
     print(f)
```

O *módulo os* também fornece a função [`scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) que segundo a documentação:

> **`os.scandir(path='.')`**
> Retorna um iterador de objetos os.DirEntry correspondentes às entradas
> no diretório fornecido por path. As entradas são produzidas em ordem
> arbitrária, e as entradas especiais '.' e '..' não são incluídas. Se
> um arquivo for removido ou adicionado ao diretório após a criação do
> iterador, não é especificado se uma entrada para esse arquivo deve ser
> incluída.
>
> Usar `scandir()` em vez de `listdir()` pode aumentar significativamente o
> desempenho do código que também precisa de tipo de arquivo ou
> informações de atributo de arquivo, porque os objetos `os.DirEntry`
> expõem essas informações se o sistema operacional fornecer ao
> digitalizar um diretório. Todos os métodos de `os.DirEntry` podem
> realizar uma chamada de sistema, mas `is_dir()` e `is_file()` normalmente
> requerem apenas uma chamada de sistema para links simbólicos;
> `os.DirEntry.stat()` sempre requer uma chamada de sistema no Unix, mas
> requer apenas uma para links simbólicos no Windows.
>
> path pode ser um objeto caminho ou similar. Se path for do tipo bytes
> (direta ou indiretamente por meio da interface PathLike), o tipo do
> atributo name e path de cada os.DirEntry serão bytes; em todas as
> outras circunstâncias, eles serão do tipo str.

```
import os

@click.command()
@click.option("--path", default=".", help="Path para ser listado.")
def ls2(path):
  with os.scandir(path) as d:
    for e in d:
        if not e.name.startswith('.') and e.is_file():
            print(f'{"f" if e.is_file() else "*"}->{e.name}')
```

Comment: ....Tentei resolver o problema como sugeriu, mas não consigo inserir todos os arquivos...

Comment: @Lara vamos e quem quiser participar vamos conversar [nessa sala de chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120201/listar-aquivos-de-lara) para debater o seu código.